# How do I prevent importing nonexistent names in ES2015?

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, babeljs

```
/* index.js */
import { React } from 'react';
import { USER, ORDER } from './StaticVariable';
class AgentList extends React.Component {
  render() {
   const useInfo = USER;
   const orderId = ORDER;
   return <Info useInfo={useInfo} orderId={orderId} />
  }
}

/* StaticVariable.js */
export const ORDER = 12347600;
```

Seems babel-loader don't throw error. And the page don't console error too.
what should I do to avoid import undefined module or variable? Using eslint?

Comment: Use an editor which will point out such errors to you. What editor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This eslint plugin does exactly what you need: [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import).

You can install it:

```
npm install eslint-plugin-import -g
```

And configure plugin in `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  ...
  "extends": [
    ...
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings"
  ],
  "plugins": [ "import" ],
  "rules": {
    "import/named": 2,
    "import/default": 2
    ...
  }
}
```

Rules you need to use are:

> Ensure named imports correspond to a named export in the remote file. ([named](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/named.md))
>
> Ensure a default export is present, given a default import. ([default](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/default.md))